# Do Esperanto organisations help other countries promote Esperanto?

Tags: organizations

My country doesn't have much Esperanto activity going on which means that it struggles to muster resources to promote Esperanto.

Do organisations like UEA officially run programmes to help create Esperanto communities in other countries?

Comment: Have you tried to contact them directly? Better get that answer (for your country) straight from the horse's mouth...

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I have. It seems those in charge have lost interest.

Comment: Why are you linking to a previous question?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge at least a couple of years ago UEA ran a promotion program in Indonesia. I do not know what results were achieved.

While the idea sounds appealling at first, there are several practical obstacles. Running such program remotely is hard, so you would need people who would translocate into another country for several weeks, if not longer. Who would pay their staying? Given the pandemia, is it even possible to translocate?

How could you gather sufficient amount of locals to take over? You cannot import enthusiasm.

However unfortunate it is, but there are still countries where getting involved in Esperanto can put oneself in life-threating risk. So it is better if the interest aspires from the locals and not from an outside organiser.

Having said that, try to gather even a small group and contact [Edukado.net](https://edukado.net), if they can provide some assistance in getting courses running in your country. Once you have enough attendees, getting organised by yourselves gets easier.

Comment: Indonesia has reached the primary level in [reta-vortaro.de](https://reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-2a.html).